# Scrapy Extract number from page text with regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, scrapy

I have been looking for a few hours on how to search all text on a page and if it matches a regex then extract it.  I have my spider set up as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        units = response.xpath('//body/text()').re(r"Units: (\d)")
        print title, units
```

I would like to pull out the number after "Units: " on the pages.  When I run scrapy on a page with Units: 351 in the body I only get the title of the page with a bunch of escapes before and after it and nothing for units.

I am new to scrapy and have a little python experience.  Any help with how to extract the integer after Units: and remove the extra escape characters "u'\r\n\t..." from the title would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As per comment here is an partial html extract of an example page.  Note this could be within different tags aside from the p in this example:

```
<body>
<div> Some content and multiple Divs here <div>
<h1>This is the count for Dala</h1>
<p><strong>Number of Units:</strong> 801</p>
<p>We will have other content here and more divs beyond</p>
</body>
```

Based on the answer below this is what got most of the way there.  Still working on removing Units: and extra escape characters.

```
units = response.xpath('string(//body)').re("(Units: [\d]+)")
```

Comment: Could you show an example location of `Units ...` text on the page? HTML code would be good. I'm pretty sure you don't need to scan all elements for it.

Comment: @alecxe Units could be anywhere on the page, not necessarily in the same location or within the same tags.  The only thing that is constant is the text "Units: ".  I included a sample page that is currently only returning a title and is empty for units.

Comment: Thanks, what about the `strong` tag, does `Number of Units:` is always inside `strong`?

Comment: @alecxe No they are not required to put any tag around it.  Just have Units:.  That is why I was trying to search the body tag and match on a regex.  I understand it is not ideal with no tag to go to but that is what I am left with.

Comment: Gotcha. Could you please provide several examples covering other cases? Would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
response.xpath('string(//body)').re(r"Units: (\d)")
```

Comment: This does get Units: 8 from the example above so this is closer.  I thought \d would pull the whole number.  I will research further must be something with my regex.  Thanks.

Comment: @Xaxum use the `\d+` instead of `\d`.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know how to get rid of all those \r\t.. characters that come across with some of the text?

Comment: @Xaxum try using ``normalize-space(//body)`` instead of ``string(//body)`` in the XPath.

Comment: @Xaxum btw, it's very helpful to know a bit of XPath for web scraping -- you may like this list of XPath tricks I collected a while back: http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/07/17/xpath-tips-from-the-web-scraping-trenches/