# How to use re statement in Scrapy?

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have this text

```
5% FIDÉLITÉ
Auchan pavés de saumon atlantique x2 -300g
3,90€
13,00 €/ kg
```

I need to get `3,90€` and `13,00 €`

I tried this regular expression for get this pattern

```
/[0-9],[0-9]*€/g
```

But, I don't know how to use it with **re** in **python scrapy**

Comment: Check [*Scrapy Extract number from page text with regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723378/scrapy-extract-number-from-page-text-with-regex) and use `r'([0-9]+,[0-9]*)\s*€'` regex (or similar).

Comment: How are you using `.re()` with Scrapy and `/[0-9],[0-9]*€/g`? Can you provide sample input (I assume the text example in your question is in some HTML markup)?

Comment: @paultrmbrth i didn't use .re() with Scrapy and /[0-9],[0-9]*€/g, i just said i just tried this regex to get my patern. i tested it in http://regexr.com/

Comment: regexr.com should be OK to test most Python regexps, but note that it only supports JavaScript regex flavor. Use regex101.com with the Python option selected, it is better and more user-friendly (IMHO). Debuggex.com and pythex.org are also good.

Comment: @parik, ok but how are you planning on using `.re()`? what scrapy object are you dealing with? If you have text input, and want to apply a regular expression, then you don't need scrapy. Otherwise, what's your input? Have you tried to run some scrapy code already? If yes and it was not successful, what did you get as output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the sites

Comment: @paultrmbrth yes you are right, i don't need Scrapy. i resolved my problem with Debuggex.com that wiktor suggested.